# What to put into consideration while adding a new Kibana-5 data source?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, kibana, silk

I'm attempting to add solr as a new data source for Kibana-5 to read from. Does it all it take is to only add a new plugin to the source code or there are other areas where I should take into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make it sound very simple: "only add a new plugin". I think this will be very hard, since Elasticsearch and its query DSL are baked into Kibana very deeply.

Lucidworks tried to fork Kibana twice:

- https://github.com/lucidworks/silk — no commits since February 2016
- https://github.com/lucidworks/banana — no commits since January 2017

You can probably take a look at their commits to get an idea, but this will be *a lot of work*.

Comment: Thank you xeraa. 
Since SiLK is a fork of Kibana4, I dived into the source code of both to have a pretty good idea what effort is required for such approach. 
Lucidworks made a lot of work to make that happen although it's not that mission impossible, and I believe it will be more complicated when it comes to kibana5 with it's new features. after that study, I decided to go 
with SiLK and work on adding new features myself.

Thanks again Xeraa for your help.

Comment: If it solved your question, please mark it as the right solution :)